# System.LimitException: Too many fields describes: 101

Tags: apex, trigger, fields

For the sake of my programming around this with a makeshift fix:

Is this implying that I am trying to write to more than 100 fields at a time across multiple records..?  Or even one record?  I can't seem to find a clear definition for this error.

Any help would be appreciated.   Thanks.

Comment: As Andrew Fawcett mentioned you may take it in map and this should resolve .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look in the code that you have not done any describe call inside the for loop

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Account.AccountNumber.getDescribe();
```

This is an example for field describe .Search for the describe calls in the code and make sure we have out of the for loop.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm

Here is the document of complete list of fielddescribe calls .

There is a limit that in a single context run you can have only 100 fielddescribe calls.This is one of the governor limits of platforms

Here is the class thats causing issue .I see getdescribe inside the for but that may not be issue but please dont call this inside the for loop .Try to bulkify

```
for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()){
        schema.describefieldresult dfield =   sfield.getDescribe();
        string fname = dfield.getname();      
        //if (fname.indexOf('pb_') > -1 && fname.indexOf(productName) > -1 )
        if (fname == ('pb_Stage_' + productName + '__c')  || fname == ('pb_SubStage_' + productName + '__c') || 
            fname == ('pb_RecordType_' + productName + '__c')  || fname == ('pb_CreateDate_' + productName + '__c') ||
            fname == ('pb_Client_' + productName + '__c')  || fname == ('pb_CloseDate_' + productName + '__c') ||
            fname == ('pb_SubBegin_' + productName + '__c')  || fname == ('pb_SubEnd_' + productName + '__c') ||
            fname == ('pb_Amount_' + productName + '__c')       )
        {
            if (dfield.isUpdateable())
                if (fname == ('pb_Client_' + productName + '__c') )
                    accObj.put(fname, false);
                else
                {
                    accObj.put(fname, null);
                }
        }
    }

    return accObj;
```

As shown above by Andrew Fawcett you may get in map and this should resolve the issue

Comment: Well, I have NO references in the code whatsoever for the following words, partial or otherwise:   Schema, Describe or Result..........................

Comment: I DO have a few references to my accObj that MAY apply........... (next comments)

Comment: On the OUTER MOST LOOP of a set of nested loops  . . . . . . . accObj = objManager.SetNullFieldsForAccount(accObj, o.Piggyback_Product_Reference__c);

Comment: Withing the either 2nd or 3rd level loop . . . . .. . accObj = objManager.SetNullFieldsForAccount(accObj, tempFieldName);

Comment: I AM doing some accObj.put action deep into the nested loops, and logic tells me I could instead accumulate the answer(s) and accObj.put them at the OUTSIDE of the loops.  Do you think THAT would help?

Comment: Please paste the code that we can debug

Comment: Well, the trigger is over 600 lines long.   :-/   Given how it was first created, and how it's been literally what I've used to cut my teeth on Apex, I think this site would have a field day with it.   Please verify if it's appropriate/logical to post such a thing.... thanks.

Comment: Ok so may be you can paste code snippet that you thing is causing failure.You can get from debug log

Comment: I honestly have NO clue how to get to a debug log (is that pathetic?).  I have output from dataLoader to help guide me which is what the TITLE of this posting was.   :-/

Comment: Or if you are UP to it, I can setup Gotomeeting so you can SEE it in action perhaps.  Totally your call obviously.

Comment: Can you mail the snippet here msrivastav13@gmail.com .I will have a look and get back

Comment: @AMM, updating your questions with additional information contributes to a cleaner and more understandable question opposed to adding it in comments to an answer.

Comment: @MohithKumar, given your update, I am unclear what I can do to fix this.  The class in question is called twice, once in a single loop near the top, and once two loops deep in an appropriate spot.   :-(   Is there a way to optimize it perhaps?

Comment: Just saw your latest update above - I will see about implementing the MAP suggested.. thanks.

Comment: @AMM You may have to also remove this getting called inside for loop .Since when called from for loop again the limit will hit.

Comment: @MohithKumar, please correct me if I'm wrong, but is the purpose of this class to simply CLEAR field(s) when called?  If so, as I am reading it and where it is called, I may simply replace it IN THE TRIGGER with simpler code (and in fact, it may already be covered by how I always start with nulls in my temp vars).   Thanks.

Comment: @AMM-Ya correct i see no need of so much code .Whole code could have been optimized

Answer (score 9):

You will likely be using the fields collection. This is the only bit currently still constrained by the governors in this area for some reason. Take a look at, [Understanding Apex Describe Information](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm), specifically section **Using Field Describe Results**

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Name;
```

The best thing to do is get the full map of fields and store this in a static if you need it from other places in your code.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> accountFields = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap();
```

Comment: I wish it were that, since now two of "you" have suggested this.  :-/  See "other comments" below.   :-/   But thanks for trying.. ugh.  This trigger is a monster, but it works FINE OTHER THAN the severely limited running of it (we can only touch one opp at a time via DataLoader or any process).

Comment: I'm hesitant to post a 600 line trigger for help, as well.

Comment: Search for .fields. (with the dots) in your code, it should jump out?

Comment: perfect!!!@AndrewFawcett +1 for your answer and thats the solution AM needs to do

Comment: I am unclear how to CUSTOMIZE this for my code.  Error is:

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Expression of type Schema.SObjectType has no member named fields at line 16 column 13  . . . . . . am I supposed to be supplying a field list (I assume not)?

Comment: Line 16 is the SECOND line of suggested code.

Comment: Apologies, I grabbed that from the Salesforce docs and didn't test it. I've updated my answer to show a more direct way to get the map.